# Update to .NET Core 6.0 in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, rider

A teammate recently updated our code base to use .NET Core 6.0 and I'm trying to build the project in JetBrains Rider.

I went to File > Preferences > Environment and clicked on the Update button for .NET.

I think I have the 6.0 SDK installed:

```
% dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.411 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
3.1.412 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.302 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
5.0.400 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.202 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

There is a `global.json` file in the project root:

```
% cat global.json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.0",
    "rollForward": "latestMajor",
    "allowPrerelease": true
  }
}
```

However, when I do Build > Build Solution, I still get the following error:

> Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141, 5): [NETSDK1045] The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0.

What else do I need to do to build the project in Rider?

Comment: Have you installed the .Net 6 SDK?

Comment: I think so? I updated .NET Core through the Preferences UI in Rider.

Comment: @DarrylBraaten Added output from `dotnet --list-sdks`.

Comment: Running `dotnet` elsewhere might not help. Can you run it inside the project folder? Besides, check if there is a `global.json` file that blocks .NET 6 SDK from loading.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the suggestions for things to look at. The output I show for `dotnet --list-sdks` is from the project root. There is a `global.json` file in the project root. It specifies the version as 6.0.0

Comment: Can you open up your Rider settings and compare to "Using JetBrains Rider" in https://www.mfractor.com/blogs/news/net-6-for-mac-with-apple-silicon-developers? That might reveal a little bit more around the setup.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. That seems to point me in the right direction. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to LexLi pointing me in the right direction. The solution here is to select the correct version of MS Build. To do this, I went to

File > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolset and Build

Then for MSBuild version, I selected 17.0. Originally version 16.0 had been selected.